# Why is the 1-form given by the derivative of argument on the punctured plane not exact?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, exterior-derivative

In [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_and_exact_differential_forms#Examples) the 1-form
$$\omega = \frac{-ydx+xdy}{x^2 + y^2}$$
is introduced as the derivative of argument on the punctured plane $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{0\}$. It is brought up as an example for a form which is closed but not exact. I can verify that it is closed:
\begin{align}
\omega =\ &\frac{-y}{x^2 + y^2}dx + \frac{x}{x^2 + y^2}dy\\
\Rightarrow d\omega =\ &\left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \frac{x}{x^2 + y^2} - \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \frac{-y}{x^2 + y^2} \right) dx \wedge dy\\
=\ &\left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \frac{x}{x^2 + y^2} + \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \frac{y}{x^2 + y^2} \right) dx \wedge dy\\
=\ &\left( \frac{y^2-x^2}{\left(x^2 + y^2\right)^2} + \frac{x^2 - y^2}{\left(x^2 + y^2\right)^2}  \right) dx \wedge dy\\
=\ &0
\end{align}
However, I am not convinced yet that $\omega$ is not exact. I understand that the argument on the punctured plane does not constitute an actual function, but maybe some other function exists which has $\omega$ as its derivative. I would just like to see a prove that $\omega$ is not exact just by looking at the expression above.

Comment: integrate $\omega$ over the unit sphere.

Comment: @Mason $$\int_{S^1} \omega = \int_{\delta B^2} \omega = \int_{B^2} d\omega = \int_{B^2} 0 = 0$$
How is this helpful?

Comment: Your computation is wrong. You can't use Stoke's theorem here since $\omega$ is not defined at $0 \in B^2$.

Comment: @WilfredMontoya . That Wikipedia article mentions *Vector Field Analogies* . Please read that carefully . Exact forms have a lot to do with gradient vector fields known from physics. Buzzword : independence of the line integral from the path between start and end point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a simply connected domain, the path integral over $\omega$ is path independent, since on such domains, it is exact (since $d\omega=0$). This means that the argument is the (up to a constant) unique integral of $\omega$. By looking at the half slit domain ($\mathbb R^2$ minus a ray emanating from the origin) it follows from this, that an integral of $\omega$ cannot be continued continuously to the plane minus the origin.